# SSIS output parameters and XML

Tags: xml, ssis, oledb

It seems that when using the OLE DB Command within SSIS problems occur when handling stored procedures that return xml: [view bug description](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=178760)

I have to use a procedure that is built in such a way and get hold of the xml even if it is just as a string value. Does anybody know of a workaround to the bug linked above that doesn't involve changing the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to use CAST operator to convert the output of your stored proc to a regular string.